# Ruby file is in search path but can't be found by 'require'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a Rails app that's trying to use the gnuplot gem, but Rails won't bother to load it. It's in my Gemfile and I installed it with bundle install. Bundle knows about it:

```
vp117025:src tim$ bundle show gnuplot
/Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/gnuplot-2.3.6
```

But it doesn't appear in the Rails console (and isn't accessible from my app), even after an explicit require, which shouldn't be necessary.

```
vp117025:src tim$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'gnuplot'
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > require 'gnuplot.rb'
 => false
```

Now, check to see whether the name of the module is in the constants table:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > Module.constants.include? :Gnuplot
 => false
```

It isn't! The module must not really be accessible. This is happening even though the require search path contains the directory that holds gnuplot.rb.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > $:.include? "/Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/gnuplot-2.3.6/lib"
 => true
```

If I include the file explicitly by its full path, it works!

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > require "/Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/gnuplot-2.3.6/lib/gnuplot.rb"
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > Module.constants.include? :Gnuplot
 => true
```

The module is now visible to the interpreter. It works just fine from outside Rails.

```
vp117025:src tim$ irb -rubygems -r gnuplot
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > Module.constants.include? :Gnuplot
 => true
```

Why can't the Rails environment load gnuplot.rb, even though its parent directory is in the search path?

Answer (score 6):

It is loading. The return value of a require statement will be `false` if the library was already loaded. When you start the Rails console, it requires all the gems in your bundle, so requiring it again will give you `false` as you see here. Require treats every path passed to it fairly literally, so you can require a file by both its relative and absolute paths, and it will load both times. That's why you get a `true` result when using the full path – Ruby is treating it as a different file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But look at the tests I'm making for `Module.constants.include? :Gnuplot` -- the Gnuplot module doesn't seem to be accessible to the interpreter until I require the file by its absolute path. Further, when I start rails console, if I try to access something that lives in the Gnuplot module (e.g. Gnuplot::gnuplot), I get NameError: uninitialized constant Gnuplot. But that call works fine after I require the file by absolute path.

Comment: Hmm. I can't replicate that. I just made a fresh Rails app, added Gnuplot, opened the console, and it was loaded. What version of Rails are you on?

Comment: Thanks for trying that! Your comment inspired me to figure out the proximate cause -- a fresh Rails app with just gnuplot works fine, but copying my Gemfile into the new project wrecked it. Commenting out gems one at a time showed that the problem turns out to be a bad reaction between the gsl and gnuplot gems -- something in the gsl gem prevents the Gnuplot namespace from appearing properly when the gsl gem is loaded first. What a headache, but now I know what to hack on!

Comment: It's the GSL Gem for sure, I'm still wondering around the web trying to find a way to use GnuPlot with GSL in a Bundled environment,  as you mentioned, works fine in IRB, but not from Rails console

Comment: @TimSmith : By the way, Thanks for the HACK!  If I add the Full Path require statement in boot.rb (before the Bundler require) it allows me to work around.

Comment: I wonder if this is kosher :) for an app I am working on I overrode require to register and check all loaded files against their full absolute path.

Was there a design reason to do this otherwise? It seems a bit like a bug.